# validation for the "version" field in a table

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, validation

I have an input field named "VERSION" in a form where I have to write the version of the document.

e.g.
Version : 10.1.2.3

How to validation for this input field in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a regular expression?

`(\d+\.)+.\d+`

Meaning: one or more digits, followed by a point, repeated as many times as you want, followed by a point and one or more digits.

If you have to have 4, you can make it more specific:

`(\d+\.){3}.\d+`

If it has to be 2 digits, one one one, try:

```
\d\d\.\d\.\d\.\d
```

As you see, you need to be more clear about "what is a valid version, and what is not" in order to obtain a more specific answer :]

Answer (score 0):

You mean you'd validate if there is a version input in the correct format?
(use an ID for the input field)

`if(document.getElementByID('VERSION').value.match(/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/)) {}`

This should match all versions in the format {number}.{number}.{number}.{number}
Maybe you have to trim the string before you do that